# ошибка при отправке сообщения smtp (javaMail)

Tags: java, javamail

Пишу рассылку для клиентов, при использовании ящика gmail или mail, да даже rambler, сообщения передаются, но при попытке использовать корпоративную почту выдает ошибку

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and
> >     Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 
> >     b126sm3310156lfe.39
> >     - gsmtp
>
> at com.company.EmailSendler.main(EmailSendler.java:50) Caused by:
>   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and
>   Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 
>   b126sm3310156lfe.39
>   - gsmtp
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:823)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:756)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:673)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   com.company.EmailSendler.main(EmailSendler.java:45)

Логин и пароль введен верно, подскажите что можно сделать?

```
   import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class EmailSendler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "info@lincoln.moscow";
        final String password = "*********";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("info@lincoln.moscow"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("i.mr.tuz@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Тестовое сообщение");
            message.setText("Работай пожалуйста,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В примере, у вас указаны настройки gmail, в рабочем коде (корпоративная почта) у вас тоже smtp имеет такой же порт? У вас не проще защита? Например у нас, гораздо проще, поэтому порт другой.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в своем Гугл аккаунте разрешить небезопасные приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это точно ответ именно на вопрос про ошибку при отправке сообщения smtp?

Comment: Да, если для рассылки используется gmail.

Comment: тогда стоит объснить (в тексте вопроса) эту неочевидную взаимосвязь.

Comment: Там в примере кода указано что используется gmail. props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

Answer (score -1):

Судя по сообщению

> Username and Password not accepted

у вас логин или пароль не правильный

Comment: Товарищ, подписал же, что пароль правильный) не в этом проблема.